# How do you pipe an OutputStream and InputStream to console?

Tags: java, inputstream, outputstream

When running a process, how do I pipe it's output to `System.out` and it's input to `System.in`:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cubc.exe");
// do something with p.getOutputStream())
```

EDIT: I think I explained this wrong; I don't want to input to the program, I want the user to input to the program, and I don't want to read the output, I want the user to read the output.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using [`IOUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) class from Apache [Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/):

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cubc.exe");
IOUtils.copy(p.getInputStream(), System.out);
```

Comment: I think I explained this wrong; I don't want to input to the program, I want the user to input to the program, and I don't want to read the output, I want the user to read the output.

Comment: @personak this does what you want. The naming of the `Process` methods is a little confusing: `getInputStream()` gets you an input stream containing the _output_ of the process, which is what is being forwarded to `System.out` here, which is what you need.

Comment: I see - that makes much more sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the input this way:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(p.getInputStream());
```

Regarding output stream, you can grab it in the same way, and print it using **System.out.*** methods:

```
OutputStream os = p.getOutputStream();
```

Comment: Downvoter - explain if you don't mind, so I will be stand corrected.

Answer (score -3):

You can't really do this with Java, per se. What you can do though is create your process and use [PipedOutputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/PipedOutputStream.html) to catch the output then write it to System.out.println. Other then that, I don't think there is any other way.

Comment: I think `System.Console.WriteLine` is C#.

Comment: It's `System.out.println` in Java.